# All series on a given axis must be of the same data type - error message while displaying datatime on the chart

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to display data from my database in MVC application using google charts. When I display "int" format it works fine, but when I want to change to for example "datetime" type I get the error message: "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type".
Here is my sample database:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgJce.jpg)

**Controller code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace GoogleProba.Controllers
{
public class GoogleChartController : Controller
{
    // GET: GoogleChart
    public ActionResult Column()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult GetSalesData()
    {
        List<SalesData> sd = new List<SalesData>();
        using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
        {
            sd = dc.SalesData.OrderBy(a => a.Data).ToList();
        }

        var chartData = new object[sd.Count + 1];
        chartData[0] = new object[]{
                "Data",
                "Electronics",
                "Book And Media",
                "Home And Kitchen"
            };
        int j = 0;
        foreach (var i in sd)
        {
            j++;
            chartData[j] = new object[] { i.Data, i.Electronics, i.BookAndMedia, i.HomeAndKitch };
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = chartData, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
}
```

**View code(updated):**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Column";
 }



 <div id="visualization" style="width:600px; height:300px">

 </div>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 @section Scripts{
 <script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    //Load Data Here
    var chartData = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/GoogleChart/GetSalesData',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ''
    }).done(function (d) {
        drawChart(d);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(d))
    }).fail(function (jq, text, errMsg) {
        console.log(errMsg);
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
  });

 function drawChart(d) {
// process date column
d.forEach(function (row, index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    return;
  }
  row[0] = row[0].replace('/', 'new ');
  row[0] = row[0].replace('/', '');
  row[0] = eval(row[0]);

});

data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(d);

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, {
    type: 'datetime',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    calc: function () { return 0; }
}, {
    type: 'number',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
    calc: function () { return 0; }
}, {
    type: 'number',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(2),
    calc: function () { return 0; }
}, {
    type: 'number',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(3),
    calc: function () { return 0; }
}]);

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
var options = {
    title: 'Sales Report',
    legend: 'bottom',
    hAxis: {
        title: 'year',
        format: '#'
    },
    vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 1000000,
        title: 'Sales Amount'
    },
    chartArea: {
        left:100, top: 50, width:'70%', height: '50%'
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 1000
    }
};

google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
});

chart.draw(view, options);
 }
</script>

 }
```

My data from the log: `[["Data","Electronics","Book And Media","Home And Kitchen"],["2016-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",345000,76666,66777],["2016-03-05T23:00:00.000Z",567000,94000,234000],["2016-05-06T22:00:00.000Z",234555,55555,678900],["2016-06-02T22:00:00.000Z",455555,555555,567000]]`

When I put "Year" from database on X axis it works very pretty but when I change to display "Data" it doesn't works, anyone can help me with that?

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data? --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(chartData))`

Comment: Sorry, I'm totaly newbie, I'm don't understant, what do you really need? Do you mean that -> [link](http://scr.hu/0wq4l/lkp7m)   ?

Comment: @Arqu07, try add the line of code posted by SO User _WhiteHat_ is his [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271198/all-series-on-a-given-axis-must-be-of-the-same-data-type-error-message-while-d#comment69745371_41271198) in your success function: like this: success: function (d) { chartData = d; console.log(JSON.stringify(chartData)) }

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mauricio! After that in console I got this: `[["Data","Electronics","Book And Media","Home And Kitchen"],["/Date(1454281200000)/",345000,76666,66777],["/Date(1457218800000)/",567000,94000,234000],["/Date(1462572000000)/",234555,55555,678900],["/Date(1464904800000)/",455555,555555,567000]]`

Comment: @Arqu07 please add your results in your question :) also, these results are when you set `Year` or `Data`, please edit your question with both results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first**, since you're *totaly newbie*...

it's recommended to use `loader.js` to load the chart library, vs. `jsapi`

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new `gstatic` loader from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see snippet below for specifics...

---

**next**, to make it easy on google, the json date needs to formatted a certain way...

`"Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, days, seconds, milliseconds)"`

e.g. --> `"Date(2016, 11, 21)"` -- or -- `"Date(2016, 11, 21, 20, 48, 18, 122)"` -- etc...

---

**however**, I'm not much help with `c#`

as such, the following script will convert the date on the client using *javascript*

(not recommended for large data sets)

---

*javascript* can use the integer to get the proper date, just needs to be in a different format

-- convert first column in array to actual date

from: `"/Date(1454281200000)/"`

to: `new Date(1454281200000)`

```
// replace first forward slash (/) with 'new'
row[0] = row[0].replace('/', 'new ');

// remove second forward slash (/)
row[0] = row[0].replace('/', '');

// evaluate the string to an actual date
row[0] = eval(row[0]);
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var rawData = [
      ["Data","Electronics","Book And Media","Home And Kitchen"],
      ["/Date(1454281200000)/",345000,76666,66777],
      ["/Date(1457218800000)/",567000,94000,234000],
      ["/Date(1462572000000)/",234555,55555,678900],
      ["/Date(1464904800000)/",455555,555555,567000]
    ];

    rawData.forEach(function (row, index) {
      // skip column labels
      if (index === 0) {
        return;
      }
      row[0] = row[0].replace('/', 'new ');
      row[0] = row[0].replace('/', '');
      row[0] = eval(row[0]);
    });

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawData);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      hAxis: {
        format: 'MMM yyyy'
      }
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

integrating into the code from the question,

you can rely on the google `callback` to know when the page is ready
instead of --> `$(document).ready`

there are a couple minor other changes, including `addOneTimeListener`

```
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
      callback: function () {
        //Load Data Here
        var chartData = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/GoogleChart/GetSalesData',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ''
        }).done(function (d) {
            drawChart(d);
        }).fail(function (jq, text, errMsg) {
            console.log(errMsg);
        });
      },
      packages:['corechart']
  });

  function drawChart(d) {
    // process date column
    d.forEach(function (row, index) {
      if (index === 0) {
        return;
      }
      row[0] = row[0].replace('/', 'new ');
      row[0] = row[0].replace('/', '');
      row[0] = eval(row[0]);
    });

    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(d);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, {
        type: 'datetime',
        label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
        calc: function () { return 0; }
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
        calc: function () { return 0; }
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        label: data.getColumnLabel(2),
        calc: function () { return 0; }
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        label: data.getColumnLabel(3),
        calc: function () { return 0; }
    }]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    var options = {
        title: 'Sales Report',
        legend: 'bottom',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'year',
            format: '#'
        },
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 1000000,
            title: 'Sales Amount'
        },
        chartArea: {
            left:100, top: 50, width:'70%', height: '50%'
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000
        }
    };

    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });

    chart.draw(view, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @WhiteHat. How should it looks in my code, couse I still have some troubles with that?

Comment: Now My data looks like this: `[["Data","Electronics","Book And Media","Home And Kitchen"],["2016-01-31T23:00:00.000Z",345000,76666,66777],["2016-03-05T23:00:00.000Z",567000,94000,234000],["2016-05-06T22:00:00.000Z",234555,55555,678900],["2016-06-02T22:00:00.000Z",455555,555555,567000]]` But still I have error message: "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type" :(

Comment: will you please edit the question with the latest version of code and data?